# Bots, Woo and Adding to carts

Tags: woocommerce, bots, cart, nofollow

Quick question here. Does anyone know how to stop bots from adding items to carts in Woocommerce? I have added a nofollow to the  tag but its still happening. We are using the Ajax enabled add to cart on the homepage, categories and archives. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question shows no research.  Use robots.txt to prevent legitimate crawlers from accessing specific links, like add to cart, on your site.

Comment: Using robots for the ajax enabled links don't stop bots from clicking a href tag.

Comment: Using robots.txt sets the directive for bots for what they should and should not crawl.  This should include JS.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/104011/how-do-i-stop-google-from-indexing-ajax-calls-within-javascript